# Passing taxonomy term through drupal_html_class() and use it as row class name

Tags: views, hooks

In a view I would like to use a excluded term reference field as source for the the row classname. But the values need to be sanitized by putting the term names through `drupal_html_class()`, otherwise the resulting classnames are not valid in every case.

How can I sanitize the values using a preprocess function?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using this preprocess function:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $field = $variables['field'];
  if ($view->id() == 'VIEW_NAME' && $view->current_display == 'DISPLAY_NAME') {
    if ($field->field == 'field_category') {
      $tid = $variables['row']->_entity->field_category->target_id;
      $term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($tid);
      $name = $term->getName();
      $variables['output'] = \Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::cleanCssIdentifier($name);
    }
  }
}
```

An alternative would be using `mytheme_views_pre_render`.

Comment: I would be very interested, which hook (hook_preprocess_views_view_field or hook_views_pre_render) is best regarding performance and caching.